# Flink shared object across jobs

Tags: apache-flink, global-object

I have a list of streaming jobs running in Flink, each job has different parallelisms.

The jobs process documents. Now I want to make a snapshot of the document that each job last processed. I can use Redis to store the document ID and the Kafka topic. But I don't want to open Redis connections for the total number of each job's parallelisms (e.g. 300 connections for 30 jobs of 10 parallelisms each)

My questions are:

1. Is it better that I put the redis in the sinking part not the RichFlatMapFunction? Do I need to only open 30 connections for 30 jobs, regardless of the parallelisms?
2. Is there even a better way to make the Object, that writes to Redis, shared across the jobs, so that only one connection is needed?

Comment: Is this a batch (DataSet, or bounded streaming data) job?

Comment: I mainly use for streaming job.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a side output with the document ID/time of processing, and run that into an operator with a parallelism of 1. Store this data wherever makes sense (Redis, etc)